# Iterated Integral of $(8x^3-36x^2y^2)dydx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

I've been struggling for a bit on this math problem from my homework.

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{3}(8x^3-36x^2y^2)dydx
$$

From what I understand and have attempted, we'll integrate with respect to $x$ first, so something like:

$$
(2x^4-12x^3y^2)\vert_{1}^{3}=160-312y^2
$$

and then another integration, this time with respect to $y$:

$$
160y-104y^3\vert_{0}^{1}=(160-104)-(0-0) = \textbf{56}
$$

Yet my book says its wrong.

I could be missing something for all I know, or could it just be something simple I'm overlooking? Regardless, I'm a bit stumped and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of integration is from the inside out, so $dy \, dx$ means you integrate with respect to $y$ first, then with respect to $x$.

So the first antiderivative is
$$\int 8x^3 - 36 x^2 y^2 \, dy = 8x^3 y - 12 x^2 y^3 + C$$
and you evaluate these at the endpoints $y = 3$ and $y = 1$:
$$\int_{y=1}^3 8x^3 - 36 x^2 y^2 \, dy = \left[8x^3 y - 12 x^2 y^3 \right]_{y=1}^3 = 16x^3 - 312 x^2.$$
The remainder of the computation I leave as an exercise.